# Why mapbox-gl.js:29 Uncaught Error: An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL keep showing? I cannot see mapbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Even though I added access token in .env file adn script in html.erb, it looks not connected?

```
.env

MAPBOX_API_KEY={{pk.eyJ1Ijoia3VtYXNhbsImEiOsafsaiJjanRxd2xvfashfuawbekfjzNGFwMmZlcG1pb3p4In0.F_-z1_nW2O3CYYNOHafafas6rC1A}}
```

```
 <script>
    const venues = <%= raw json_escape(@geojson.to_json) %>;
    const mapkey = "<%= ENV['pk.eyJ1Ijoia3VtYXNhbsImEiOsafsaiJjanRxd2xvfashfuawbekfjzNGFwMmZlcG1pb3p4In0.F_-z1_nW2O3CYYNOHafafas6rC1A'] %>";
  </script>
```

```
mapbox-gl.js:29 Uncaught Error: An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL. See https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#access-tokens-and-token-scopes
    at D (mapbox-gl.js:29)
    at Object.t.normalizeStyleURL (mapbox-gl.js:29)
    at i.loadURL (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at r._updateStyle (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at r.setStyle (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at new r (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at initMapbox (init_mapbox.js:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (application.js:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (application.js:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1390f89f8aab11f4fe21:19)
```

Map should be shown

Answer (score 0):

A little late answer perhaps, if you take a look at the example here you can see how it works.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please add an explanation as to how and why that links solves the problem?

Comment: The question doesn't really make a lot of sense since it is trying to use the library in the way that is not possible. The ENV variable is also `MAPBOX_API_KEY ` in this case not the full API key.